# What is the most succinct Scala way to invoke a Java 8 functional interface?

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

Take a Runnable, for example.  What is the most succinct way to call this from Scala?

I'm currently doing this:

```
r { () => runnable-body; null; }
```

after having declared the following trait:

```
trait Implicits {
    def r(fun: () => Unit) = new Runnable { def run() = fun() }
}
```

But this has two flaws:

- It's only for Runnable, not for all functional interfaces.
- There must be a more succinct way to express this.  Compare with Java 8's simpler `() -> runnable-body`.

Comment: Why did you add null?

Comment: In many of our runnable-body cases, the last expression doesn't return null.  So, without the final null, it wouldn't compile.  But I'm very open to alternate ways of writing this.  And the original question remains, even without the null issue (i.e., consider a runnable-body having a final expression that returns void, in which case the null; could be omitted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make the adapter take `() => Any` to avoid the need for the `null`.

Scala is working on support for Java 8 SAM synthesis but it won't be marked stable until 2.12; you can build with `-Xexperimental` to enable it in current versions. Other than that as far as I can see you'll need adapters for every case (maybe a macro could help generate them).